# expectation of $n$ people occupy $n$ seats without adjoint

Tags: probability

It is an interview question:

> $n$ people occupy $n$ seats. Each person will randomly choose a seat one by one, but they cannot choose the adjacent seat of already been occupied. What's the expected number of occupied seats in the end.

I am not sure interviewer want a closed form or coding by dynamic programing. What I achieved is $n$ people occupy $m$ seats where $m\geq n+2.$ We can use indicator $X_i:$ i-th person without adjacent people:
$$E[X_i]=\dfrac{2}{m}(\textrm{at begin or end})\times \dfrac{C_{m-2}^{n-1}}{C_{m-1}^{n-1}}+\dfrac{m-2}{m}(\textrm{in mid})\times \dfrac{C_{m-3}^{n-1}}{C_{m-1}^{n-1}}.$$

here $C_a^b$ is Combination number: select b from a. But I don't know how to deal with $m=n$ case.

**Edit:**
One iterative formula is not correct:
$$E_{n,m} = \dfrac{2}{m}E_{n-1, m-2} + \dfrac{m-2}{m}E_{n-1, m-3}.$$
If the first guy set at i-th middle seat in $E_{n,m}$, then the seats for $E_{n-1,m-2}$ is 1,2,...,i-2,i+2,...... In $E_{n,m},$ i-2 and i+2 can set two people since they are not adjoint seats. However in $E_{n-1,m-3},$ it is not allowed since they are adjoint seats.

Comment: It's expected that you'll ask questions during an interview. What was the interviewer's feedback? Did he ask you any questions along the way or just observe in silence? Did you explain your thought process?

Comment: Let $E_{n, m}$ be the expected number of seats occupied given $n$ people and $m$ seats.


Then $E_{n, n} =  \frac{2}{n}E_{n-1, n-2} + \frac{n-2}{n}E_{n-1, n-3}$. That is, if the first guy randomly chooses an end seat that leaves $n-2$ seats available for $n-1$ people and the problem recurses. Similarly if the person chooses a middle seat that leaves $n-3$ seats available for $n-1$ people and the problem recurses. The base cases are easy enough to see.

Comment: @Vercingetorix I think this is the answer I want, do you want to write down as an answer, I will accept it? and $E_{0,n}=E_{n,0}=0, right?$

Comment: @Vercingetorix here is my rule of update: $E_{n,2}=E_{n,1}=1,E_{n,0}=E_{0,n}=0$ for all $n.$ Then update as `for (int n=3; n<=N; ++n), for (int m = 3; m<=n; ++m)`

Comment: @Vercingetorix you formula seems not correct. Pls see my update

Answer (score 1):

The question is the same if there is an infinite number of people. Forgetting about the number of people makes the recurrence simpler. Cal $E_n$ the expected number of occupied seats when no legal seats are left.

If person $1$ chooses the first or last seat, the expected number of occupied seats is $1 + E_{n-2}$.

If person $1$ chooses the $k$th seat with $k \neq 1, n$, the expected number of occupied seats is $1 + E_{k-2} + E_{n-k-1}$, because there is a sequence of $k-2$ legal seats left before them and $n-k-1$ seats after them, and it does not matter in what order or with what probability the people choose either of these sequences because there are enough people to fill all the seats.

So
$$\begin{align*}
E_n &= 1 + \frac1n\left( 2 E_{n-2} + \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} (E_{k-2} + E_{n-k-1}) \right) \\
&= 1 + \frac{2}n (E_0 + \cdots + E_{n-2}) \,.
\end{align*}$$
The starting values are $E_0= 0$, $E_1 = 1$. You can compute the recurrence up to $E_n$ in linear time.